# JQuery doesn't permanently remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove the "hidden" class from a message when the button is clicked.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#error').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

But it only seems to work on the actual click and not after release like it should.

[image: screenshot]

I just started learning javascript, I'd appreciate any help with this.

If this isn't the correct way to do this, please suggest an alternative :)

Comment: This is impossible to answer, as jQuery does indeed permanently remove the class. I'm guessing the button is in a form, and the page reloads ?

Comment: Try to post some more code or a jsfiddle of your problem.

Comment: It's just a button element with id "#error" and class "hidden", in css I have display:hidden for .hidden class. I run the script add the end of the html body. Browser is chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a button by default submits the form. If you do not want it to submit, you need to cancel the default action of it.

```
$('#button').click(function (evt) {
    $('#error').removeClass('hidden');
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I'd transpose the 2 lines and prevent the default event first. Also may be good to add `evt.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Or alternatively, define the button as `<button type="button">`.

Answer (score 0):

So my input here is that you are reverting back in your code somewhere, whether you are submitting (which will refresh and reapply your css 'display:hidden') or you are possibly calling another function that is reapplying the class 'hidden'

```
$('#button').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $('#error').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8jws4cx6/